# Develop for Windows 8 using Windows 7?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, winapi

Is it possible to develop Windows 8 apps using Windows 7?

According to the page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx#Requirements

Windows 7 is supported, by the SDK. I downloaded it.

Now I want to download visual studio (free, that's express, right?), but found only this:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads#vs

According to this:

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/products/compatibility

It should run on Windows 7. The only free download I found is Express "for Windows 8" -

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads#express-win8

And yeah, it runs only on Windows 8.

What do I have to download to develop for Windows 8 on Windows 7?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Windows 8 SDK by itself is not an IDE like Visual Studio. Nor does it come with a compiler. So yes, you can install it on Windows 7, but you won't be able to do much with it unless you are willing to do a lot of work. You won't have any templates or things like that. The simplest way to build Windows Store apps (formerly referred to as Metro style) is to use Visual Studio and/or Blend running on a Windows 8 machine - running directly on a machine (recommended) or in a virual environment.

Comment: Hm, well, this would be the release preview, right? There's no Windows 8 released yet... is the suggestion to use VS2010 on Windows 7 very difficult to do? I'll try it, before I have to make a partition, or virtual environment only for Windows 8 release preview...

Comment: I don't believe you'll be able to use VS2010 on Windows 7 to create Windows Store apps on Windows 7 even if you downloaded the SDK. You'd be able to author the raw files of the app using a text editor, stating the appropriate references, using the header files in there, etc. But you won't be able to compile the app, and you certainly won't be able to run it. If you visit http://aka.ms/gowin8 you can dowload Windows 8 and VS 2012 RTM now for development via your MSDN subscription or download an evaluation copy of Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

You are confused between `Visual Studio for Windows 8` and `Windows 8 SDK`. Windows 8 SDK does not require `Visual Studio for Windows 8`.

See its [System Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363.aspx#Requirements).

Comment: I am confused about everything :) But the question is, how do I develop for Windows 8 using Windows 7.

Comment: Just download Windows 8 SDK and install it in Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to VS2010 C# Express
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-csharp-express

Download and install that

Download and install .net 4.5 (mentioned in the requirements you linked in your question)

Download and install Win8 SDK

From there hopefully in VS2010 C# Express you'll be able to target .NET 4.5 and include references to the Win8 SDK stuff in your project

Comment: Ah, OK. I downloaded the SDK and .net 4.5 but was confused about the IDE / development environment. Thought for a moment it was possible to get one for Windows 8 only if using Windows 8 as OS.

Comment: If you've done .net 4.5 and the sdk already just need to do the IDE next then

Answer (score 0):

You cannot develop Windows 8 (as in WinRT apps) apps on Windows 7. You need to install Windows 8 whether it's natively or virtually.

Answer (score 0):

There are very few resources out there that are up to date. Check you [this](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/oem?contentName=docs%2FGetting_Started%2FPreparing_for_Windows_Phone_development) from Microsoft Dev Center

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. 
[Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: when I get a chance I will elaborate.